# Quickly determine the approximate maximum of an integer vector

Tags: rcpp

I'd like to use the fact that `pmax(x, 0) = (x + abs(x)) / 2` on an integer vector using Rcpp for performance.

I've written a naive implementation:

```
IntegerVector do_pmax0_abs_int(IntegerVector x) {
  R_xlen_t n = x.length();
  IntegerVector out(clone(x));
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int oi = out[i];
    out[i] += abs(oi);
    out[i] /= 2;
  }
  return out;
}
```

which is indeed performant; however, it invokes undefined behaviour should `x` contains any element larger than `.Machine$integer.max / 2`.

Is there a way to quickly determine whether or not the vector would be less than `.Machine$integer.max / 2`? I considered a bit-shifting but this would not be valid for negative numbers.

Comment: Have you considered `int64_t` for intermediate results?

Comment: I have not. Thanks for the suggestion! Would it just require an extra coercion step at the end of the for loop?

Comment: I suggest this package I'd read [link](https://github.com/EMacherki/IntegerSort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can make use of `int64_t` for intermediate results. In addition, it makes sense to not copy `x` to `out` and don't initilize `out` to zero everywhere:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector do_pmax0_abs_int(IntegerVector x) {
    R_xlen_t n = x.length();
    IntegerVector out(clone(x));
    for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int oi = out[i];
        out[i] += abs(oi);
        out[i] /= 2;
    }
    return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector do_pmax0_abs_int64(IntegerVector x) {
    R_xlen_t n = x.length();
    IntegerVector out = no_init(n);
    for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int64_t oi = x[i];
        oi += std::abs(oi);
        out[i] = static_cast<int>(oi / 2);
    }
    return out;
}

/***R
ints <- as.integer(sample.int(.Machine$integer.max, 1e6) - 2^30)
bench::mark(do_pmax0_abs_int(ints),
            do_pmax0_abs_int64(ints),
            pmax(ints, 0))[, 1:5]

ints <- 2L * ints
bench::mark(#do_pmax0_abs_int(ints), 
            do_pmax0_abs_int64(ints), 
            pmax(ints, 0))[, 1:5]
*/
```

Result:

```r
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('57310889/code.cpp')

> ints <- as.integer(sample.int(.Machine$integer.max, 1e6) - 2^30)

> bench::mark(do_pmax0_abs_int(ints),
+             do_pmax0_abs_int64(ints),
+             pmax(ints, 0))[, 1:5]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  expression                    min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>               <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 do_pmax0_abs_int(ints)     1.91ms   3.31ms     317.     3.82MB
2 do_pmax0_abs_int64(ints)   1.28ms   2.67ms     432.     3.82MB
3 pmax(ints, 0)              9.85ms  10.68ms      86.9   15.26MB

> ints <- 2L * ints

> bench::mark(#do_pmax0_abs_int(ints), 
+             do_pmax0_abs_int64(ints), 
+             pmax(ints, 0))[, 1:5]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  expression                    min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>               <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 do_pmax0_abs_int64(ints)   1.28ms   2.52ms     439.     3.82MB
2 pmax(ints, 0)              9.88ms  10.83ms      89.5   15.26MB
```

Notes:

- Without `no_init` the two C++ methods are equally fast.
- I ave removed the original method from the second benchmark, since `bench::mark` compares the results by default, and the original method produces wrong results for that particular input.

Comment: @Hugh Actually it is even faster to just go through the vector and find the maximum value at each step, c.f. https://stubner.me/2019/08/xy-problems/.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf! I concur with your link's conclusion with the lambda function.  I was comparing the abs trick with branching every iteration: `if (x[i] < 0) out[i] = 0`. I worked out that calculating the maximum then doing the abs trick was faster than the branching method alone, and knew that ABS() was implemented at a very low level, so assumed that it was the fastest method.